# How can I get my webapp's base URL in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

How can I quickly determine what the root URL is for my ASP.NET MVC application?  I.e., if IIS is set to serve my application at http://example.com/foo/bar, then I'd like to be able to get that URL in a reliable way that doesn't involve getting the current URL from the request and chopping it up in some fragile way that breaks if I re-route my action.

The reason that I need the base URL is that this web application calls another one that needs the root to the caller web application for callback purposes.

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Assuming you have a Request object available, you can use:

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
```

If it's not available, you can get to it via the context:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: I tried this, but neither HttpContext.Current.Request.Authority, nor HttpContext.Current.Request.Scheme was defined.

Comment: What is `urlHelper.Content("~")`? How do I create define `urlHelper`? Thanks!

Comment: @Maxim, you can problably substitute **Url.Content("~")**

Comment: var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

Comment: What I ended up using: `var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            urlBase = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, (new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(request.RequestContext)).Content("~"));`

Comment: For MVC 4 I use `ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request`

Comment: What happens when you are behind a load balancer and the server is really taking requests at http://10.55.44.33:1234 when the public url is https://www.example.com ?

Comment: @WyattBarnett: You put the public URL root in a config file. There is no zero-config solution for that case (except constructing the URLs with JS on the client side - but that would work only for simple links and would not degrade gracefully).

Comment: @WyattBarnett: Ah, I didn't realize you were the owner of _that_ answer (which I had upvoted) and thought you were asking here genuinely.

Comment: `@Url.Content("~")` resolves to `"/"`, which isn't the base url.

Comment: @WyattBarnett I guess it should really be doing something like  getting the host from Request.Headers["x-forwarded-host"]

Comment: @PaulZahra sure if that is how your proxy is configured -- you don't have to pass that through at all, and x-* headers are all non-standard to boot.

Comment: returns invalid url for cases where you are behind ngrok tunnel and https

Answer (score 140):

So none of the ones listed here worked for me, but using a few of the answers, I got something working:

```
public string GetBaseUrl()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var appUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

    if (appUrl != "/") 
        appUrl = "/" + appUrl;

    var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, appUrl);

    return baseUrl;
}
```

**Update for ASP.NET Core / MVC 6:**

`ASP.NET Core` makes this process a bit more painful, especially if you are deep in your code. You have 2 options to get at the `HttpContext`

1) Pass it in from your `controller`:

```
var model = new MyClass(HttpContext);
```

then in `model`:

```
private HttpContext currentContext;

public MyClass(HttpContext currentContext)
{
    this.currentContext = currentContext;
}
```

2) Perhaps the cleaner way is to inject it into your class, which starts with registering the types in your `Startup:`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<MyClass, MyClass>();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

then have it injected for you like this:

```
private HttpContext currentContext;

public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    currentContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
}
```

in either case, here is the updated for `.NET Core` `GetBaseUrl()`:

```
public string GetBaseUrl()
{
    var request = currentContext.Request;

    var host = request.Host.ToUriComponent();

    var pathBase = request.PathBase.ToUriComponent();

    return $"{request.Scheme}://{host}{pathBase}";
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this method?

Comment: That really depends on how often you need to use it... if this is a single use deal then just put it in the class where you need this data, if you anticipate using it in multiple classes in your app, then I use a folder called `Helpers` in the base of my app, I have a `static` class called `Statics` and I put functions like the above there... just make sure you change the above from `public string GetBaseUrl()` to `public static string GetBaseUrl()`

Comment: As an update, I no longer use a class called `Statics`, instead I have it broken apart into more specific uses, so in this case this would go into my `UrlHelper` class

Comment: `Host.ToUriComponent()`, finally, and I was able to get request object with `Url.ActionContext.HttpContext` in view

Comment: In the `view` you just need to use `@Context`to get at the `HttpContext`... please don't use `Url.ActionContext.HttpContext`...

Comment: Of all the options that I have found, this is the only one that actually worked for me.  Your #2 that is. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Upvoted this because it's the only one to mention PathBase, which is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, misses the `port` part though.

Answer (score 76):

In Code:

```
Url.Content("~/");
```

MVC3 Razor Syntax:

```
@Url.Content("~/")
```

Comment: This is fine for using on the Razor pages, but if you're trying to pass the URL to an external source, it won't give you the full URL.

Comment: It doesn't work. It'll just add `/` instead of actual name.

Comment: Where is Code does the `Url` helper available to you right off the bat? Maybe only in the `Controller`. Certainly not in the `ViewModel` or any other `class` where you may need this..

Answer (score 46):

Maybe it is extension or modification of the answers posted here but I use simply the following line and it works:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Content("~")
```

When my path is: `http://host/iis_foldername/controller/action`
then I receive : `http://host/iis_foldername/`

Answer (score 28):

The following snippet works nicely for me in MVC4, and doesn't need an `HttpContext` available:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath
```

Comment: Seems to work in MVC3 too. I use it in `jQuery.load()` to construct the URL for the controller and action I want to call:  
`$('#myplaceholder').load('@(Html.Raw(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath))/MyController/MyAction', ...);`

Comment: why would you do that? instead of calling Url.Action?

Comment: Doesn't work when deployed to Azure. Higher rated answers work in this scenario.

Answer (score 25):

The trick with relying upon IIS is that IIS bindings can be different from your public URLs (WCF I'm looking at you), especially with multi-homed production machines. I tend to vector toward using configuration to explicitly define the "base" url for external purposes as that tends to be a bit more successful than extracting it from the Request object.

Comment: Also true for servers behind load balancers or proxies.

Answer (score 21):

For an absolute base URL use this. Works with both HTTP and HTTPS.

```
new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~"))
```

Answer (score 16):

[This is a conversion of an asp.net property to MVC](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/) . It's a pretty much all singing all dancing get root url method.

Declare a helper class:

```
namespace MyTestProject.Helpers
{
    using System.Web;

    public static class PathHelper
    {
        public static string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath(HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase)
        {
            string appPath = string.Empty;

            if (httpRequestBase != null)
            {
                //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
                appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                            httpRequestBase.Url.Scheme,
                            httpRequestBase.Url.Host,
                            httpRequestBase.Url.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + httpRequestBase.Url.Port,
                            httpRequestBase.ApplicationPath);
            }

            if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                appPath += "/";
            }

            return appPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

To use from a controller:

```
PathHelper.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath(ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request)
```

To use in a view:

```
@using MyTestProject.Helpers

PathHelper.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath(Request)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that accounts for the possibility of a site running on a port other than 80. All of the other answers are unsafe as far as I am concerned. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

In MVC _Layout.cshtml:

```
<base href="@Request.GetBaseUrl()" />
```

Thats what we use!

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
public static string GetBaseUrl(this HttpRequestBase request)
        {
          if (request.Url == (Uri) null)
            return string.Empty;
          else
            return request.Url.Scheme + "://" + request.Url.Authority + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `<base>`.  Also you can omit the Scheme such that it will work with http or https.  That means you can start the url with `//`.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me (also with a load balancer):

```
@{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var baseurl = urlHelper.Content(“~”);
}

<script>
    var base_url = "@baseurl";
</script>
```

Especially if you are using non-standard port numbers, using Request.Url.Authority appears like a good lead at first, but fails in a LB environment.

Answer (score 4):

In .net core 3.1 I used this approach:

```
$"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Url.Content("~/")}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have a static method that looks at HttpContext.Current and decides which URL to use (development or live server) depending on the host ID. HttpContext might even offer some easier way to do it, but this is the first option I found and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following script in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URL = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET MVC 4 it is a bit different:

```
string url = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working in ASP .NET MVC 4
 In any controller action you can write:
1stline gets the whole url+Query String.
2nd line remove local path & query ,last '/' symbol.
3rd line add '/' symbol at last position.

```
Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string UrlLink = url.OriginalString.Replace(url.PathAndQuery,"");
UrlLink = String.Concat(UrlLink,"/" );
```

Answer (score 3):

in simple html and ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC if you are using  tag:

```
<a href="~/#about">About us</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

On the webpage itself:

```
<input type="hidden" id="basePath" value="@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority,
  Url.Content("~"))" />
```

In the javascript:

```
function getReportFormGeneratorPath() {
  var formPath = $('#reportForm').attr('action');
  var newPath = $("#basePath").val() + formPath;
  return newPath;
}
```

This works for my MVC project, hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

For url with aplication alias like http://example.com/appAlias/... You can try this:

```
var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", req.Url.Scheme, req.Url.Authority, req.ApplicationPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

This was my solution (using .net core 3.1, in an api controller):

```
string baseUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Headers.Where(h => h.Key == "Host").First().Value}";
```

Answer (score 2):

For MVC 4:

```
String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Url.Request.RequestUri.Scheme, Url.Request.RequestUri.Authority, ControllerContext.Configuration.VirtualPathRoot);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a better solution.

```
@{
   var baseUrl = @Request.Host("/");
}
```

using

```
<a href="@baseUrl" class="link">Base URL</a>
```

Comment: I did not test, but I doubt this will work when the base url is a virtual directly. ie. localhost/myApp

Answer (score 2):

I put this in the head of my _Layout.cshtml

```
 <base href="~/" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@{
    var baseurl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + Url.Content("~");
}
@baseurl
```

--output
http://localhost:49626/TEST/

Answer (score 1):

The following worked solidly for me

```
var request = HttpContext.Request;
                        var appUrl = System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

                        if (appUrl != "/")
                            appUrl = "/" + appUrl + "/";

                        var newUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}/{4}", request.Url.Scheme, request.UrlReferrer.Host, appUrl, "Controller", "Action");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply in one line get BaseUrl

```
string baseUrl = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~")).AbsoluteUri;

//output example: https://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: I'm not getting `Request.Url` and `Url.Content()`. What do I need to import to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this. For the razor pages, it is better to use it than the others.

https://ml-software.ch/posts/getting-the-base-url-for-an-asp-net-core-mvc-web-application-in-your-static-javascript-files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href='@Url.AbsoluteContent("~/")'>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - ASP.NET Core Web Application</title>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this function in static class in project like utility class:

**utility.cs** content:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(request.RequestContext);
        var baseUrl = $"{request.Url.Scheme}://{request.Url.Authority}{urlHelper.Content("~")}";
        return baseUrl;
    }
}
```

use this code any where and enjoy it:

```
var baseUrl = Utility.GetBaseUrl();
```