# Using XmlTextReader to read a file on the same server via http

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm sure there's something blindingly obvious I'm missing here.

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 app with an XML doc at /content/mydoc.xml. I'm trying to load it using XmlTextReader:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("/content/mydoc.xml");
```

Stepping through, I can see that this is being resolved to `file:///C:/content/mydoc.xml`

I know I can use `Server.MapPath()` to get the file path but that seems rather hackish given that the XML doc is available via http.

Is there a way to get XmlTextReader to properly resolve the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
XmlTextReader reader = 
    new XmlTextReader(Url.GenerateContentUrl("~/content/mydoc.xml"));
```

Of course, you'll need an UrlHelper instance to hand to accomplish this (available as the Url field in view and controller).

EDIT

If I know where the file lives I'd prefer to go for it as a file, not with the overhead of HTTP. As such `MapPath` seems like a good choice here.

Comment: Thanks. However, this just seems to resolve ~/content/mydoc.xml back to /content/mydoc.xml. I can use the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc to get the base URL and construct the full URL, but that seems rather convoluted for something that seems like it should be simple

Comment: +1 for accessing the file via the file system rather than HTTP, unless you have a specific reason to do it.

Comment: Cheers guys - it does indeed make more sense.