# catching base url when using catchall maproute of asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute, url-action

If I use a maproute like

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The resulting url of `Url.Action("","")` is like `www.mysite.com/` which is base url of my site. but when I use the one with asterisk like

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The resulting url of `Url.Action("","")` is like `www.mysite.com/Home/Index/`, but in second case I want to obtain `www.mysite.com/` which is my base url. What should I do for that?

Comment: Didn't you just asked it?

Comment: This is different although they look each other. Maybe I can combine questions but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy my need; I need to obtain www.mysite.com/ when I use catchall maproute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to catch base url. One can get base url with using`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc#answer-11886035).