# Retrieve base URL as a custom field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an absolute path url so i can send to users via json:

So far i did it this way:

First, I created a static class with a static string:

```
public static class baseUrl
{
    public static string getBaseUrl(){
        return "http://myurl";
    }
}
```

Second, on the model, I created a custom column that concatenates the string and creates a new field with the full absolute path:

```
public string Image
   {
    get
    {
        return baseUrl.getBaseUrl()+"/images/" +Id+ "/content/" + Img;
    }
}
```

My question is if there is a way to get the base url instead of using a static string, so it will be automatically changed on different environments, or if there is a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Use [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) methods to do this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

debug request object , you will find base url of your current application in some property of this object.

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request
```

for more help visit this link

[How can I get my webapp's base URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc)