# Getting URL without port when running from VS, or without application name when running in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

My application's URL looks like that when I run from debugger

```
http://localhost:52230/
```

And in IIS:

```
http://localhost/MyApp
```

Or, when I'm browsing from another PC,

```
http://192.168.168.11/MyApp
```

Where MyApp = my application's name.

Is there a way, using razor syntax, to get `http://localhost` or `http://192.168.168.11` only?

I tried `@Url.Content("~/)` but it returns me `http://localhost:52230/`

Comment: You should be able to get `http://localhost` ofter you publish your project, if you set it to be the default website in IIS.

Comment: But I need something common that will work on both situations

Comment: Do you want to use it in your code or just see it in the browser?

Comment: I need a solution that gets me `http://localhost` whether I run in IIS, or from VS

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1288383/205859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@(Context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Context.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look through the HttpContext.Request  headers there is a header called "Host" that gives me Localhost (I run mine through iis Localhost) So for you this should give you Localhost/MyApp, when I run it from another computer this host gives me the ip of the computer iis is running on.

Otherwise in Request.Url are 3 properties that gives me what you need, DnssafeHost (as mentinoed by Nilzor) Authority and Host, I think the easiest way to get it would be through

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to do ::

```
  var _rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
```

Use this Function for proper Route independent on root:

```
function rootUrl(url) {                                                    
var _rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
var x = url;
if (url.indexOf(_rootUrl) != 0) {
    x = _rootUrl + "/" + url;
    x = x.replace(/\/\//g, "/").replace(/\/\//g, "/");
}
return x;
```

};

use it as::

```
rootUrl("ControllerName/ActionName");
```