# What should be my url when I´m sending via Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have web Application when I´m implementing Recovery Password, so I send vía mail link to recover Password like this:

```
 string page = "<a href ='../SPA/cuenta/cambiarContrasena.html' >RecoveryPassword</ a >";
```

I get Google Advice:

> The page you are trying to target is an invalid URL
>   (http://../SPA/cuenta/cambiarContrasena).

Problem is that no redirects to my web page, how can I do to get exactly route I want? Regards

Comment: It should be absolute url.

Comment: It should be a full URL, including the domain, and ideally, the protocol (http,https).  If you are trying to build it via code, you will probably need to set the domain name as a string in some kind of configuration that you append the rest of the path to.

Comment: How can I change it to absolute Url? just adding full path? it can´t be dinamyc? there is not a function to call url? because what happen if I´m in production or I´m testing in local, url should be different no? @Shyju

Comment: you can write code to get the base url of the site and use that to build the absolute url. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: It works Thankyou ! @Shyju