# Equivalent of UseUrls for .NET Core 3.1/IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Previously, with .NET Core 2.2, I could add `UseUrls` to my `Program.cs` file to set the URL that the web server would run on:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:5100");
```

However, in .NET Core 3.1, the default format of `Program.cs` changed:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

I tried adding `UseUrls` to this in the same manner as I did with .NET Core 2.2, but it says that:

> 'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseUrls' and the best extension method overload 'HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseUrls(IWebHostBuilder, params string[])' requires a receiver of type 'IWebHostBuilder'

How can I set the URL for the server to run on using .NET Core 3.1 (which uses `IHostBuilder` instead of `IWebHostBuilder`)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` allows you to configure the web host. One of the thing you can do is change the urls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#urls

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5100");
            });
```