# Cannot change port when migrating to .net core 3.1.3 from 2.2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

On 2.2.0, I have the following to create a WebHostBuilder. I then call `.Build().Run()` on it

```
        public IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions, Type startupType, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(commandLineOptions?.Args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
                    {
                        configBuilder.Sources.Clear();
                        configBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
                    })
                    .UseEnvironment(configuration.GetValue<string>("Environment"))
                    .UseStartup(startupType)
                    .UseUrls(configuration.GetValue<string>("HostUrl"))  //"http://*:8000/"
                    .UseSerilog(logger);
            }

            return builder;
        }
```

After upgrading to 3.1.3, it still works. I then changed to the below based on the migration doc

```
        public IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions, Type startupType, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(commandLineOptions?.Args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
                    {
                        configBuilder.Sources.Clear();
                        configBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
                    })
                    .UseEnvironment(configuration.GetValue<string>("Environment"))
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {                        
                        webBuilder.UseStartup(startupType);
                        webBuilder.UseUrls(configuration.GetValue<string>("HostUrl")); //"http://*:8000/"
                    })                                        
                    .UseSerilog(logger);
            }

            return builder;
        }
```

However, now no matter what I do it listens on the default ports of http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001.
I don't have a hostsettings.json file, launchSettings.json also has nothing set, there's no setting in my enviroment variables. I've run from the command line specifying the desired url, but nothing works.

EDIT: Thanks to Martin Staufcik's suggestion to minimize the configuration, I've noticed that changing `ConfigureAppConfiguration` to `ConfigureHostConfiguration` has resolved the issue. I also noticed that if I left it as `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and remove the `configBuilder.Sources.Clear();` line, it works too.

I've looked up the difference between the two, but I still don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: have you tried to specify the address `http://localhost:8000/` (instead of `http://*:8000/`)?

Comment: You might try to simplify the configuration to a minimum, according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347751/equivalent-of-useurls-for-net-core-3-1-ihostbuilder

Answer (score 0):

I lost a couple of hours working with `.UseUrls` myself. I finally got it working after noticing that the order of code lines was important! What worked in my case was calling `UseUrls` before `UseStartup`.

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{                        
    webBuilder.UseUrls(configuration.GetValue<string>("HostUrl")); //"http://*:8000/"   
    webBuilder.UseStartup(startupType);
})
```

Comment: I tried it both before and after. It doesn't seem to make a difference in my case