# How to access HTTP port 5001 from public internet

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ip, nat, windows-server

I have Windows Server 2016 Data center x64, .NET Core SDK 5.0 preview, Microsoft SQL Server 2019

[image]

On server: https://localhost:5001/publisher/all ok

On server https://127.0.0.1:5001/publisher/all ok

On server: Firewall Open port 5000-6000 outbound

from my computer (or any PC on the world) https://45.118.145.72:5011/publisher/all not ok

[image]

How to access https://45.118.145.72:5011/publisher/all from public internet?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you shouldn’t tell everybody your public IP address.

Comment: There are many options how you can run an asp net core app and you didn't tell us which one you're using. Setting the IP from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 might solve the problem, see `UseUrls()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347751/equivalent-of-useurls-for-net-core-3-1-ihostbuilder, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @ChristophLütjen you can post your anser, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.NET core apps bind to the "localhost" network interface with default settings. This network interface is not available from other hosts.

You can modify this using `UseUrls()`during host setup.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5001");
        });
```

Examples:

```
webBuilder.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5001"); // only from localhost
webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001"); // only from localhost
webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5001");   // allow all hosts
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps

Answer (score 2):

change to `0.0.0.0`

File `launchSettings.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51632",
      "sslPort": 44360
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "publisher/all",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "acc_ai": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "publisher/all",
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

go to https://localhost:5001/news/all from internal server.

got to https://public_ip:5001/news/all from public internet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to port forward Port 5001 at our firewall/router.