# My .NET Core Web App doesn't work in server

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core

I create an app directly on the server (dotnet new webapp), build it & run (dotnet run). The terminal shows that the app is available from a link http://localhost:port, but when I paste the ip:port into the browser, the site doesn't load. I tried to change the ports (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT), without success.
Guides in Google don't help...
SOS!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010812/how-to-access-http-port-5001-from-public-internet/63011846#63011846

Comment: Maybe there is something configured in your browser like a proxy server or special DNS server. Did you tried `curl <url>` on the console, e.g. `curl --head http://localhost:3000`? Alternatively, you may have a firewall blocking those requests.

Comment: Don't help...
I think that I messed up ports... In the Apache config, I changed the port to 8080, in the nginx config to 80. Is that it?