# NET Core 3.0: Custom URL ports not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hosting, .net-core-3.0

I've recently updated a project from netcoreapp 2.2 to 3.0. When I debug the project locally it is running on the default ports `5000` and `5001`.

[image]

I have specified specific urls in both `UseUrls` and the `launchsettings.json` file, but they are all being ignored.

[image]

[image]

Any idea why these configurations are not being picked up, and why it is resorting to using the default ports? Thanks.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347751/equivalent-of-useurls-for-net-core-3-1-ihostbuilder

Comment: Hi Flurin, its not. I'm using `UseUrls` as seen in my screenshot, but it isn't working

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#urls
the format needs to be a semicolon delimited list. Have you tried something such as:
`.UseUrls("https://localhost:8080;https://localhost:8081");`

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately no change, still runs on `5000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Our solution was not using the `Startup`'s constructor to access the instance of `IConfiguration`. We had a convenience method doing this to only grab the `appsettings.json` config, meaning we missed out on any other config .NET Core needed for setting up the app. This wasn't required in 2.2, but obviously is now.

Hope this helps anyone else.

**Solution**
Get `IConfiguration` via `Startup` constructor:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to sequence of adding services
Can you try to change it to this:

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
     webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
     webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Comment: Tried each variation of this but it still runs on `5000`