How to determine if page or controller is the entry point of the website (the home page)?
In ASP.NET Core, from within a page or a controller, how can I check if that page or controller is the home page of the website? By "home page", I mean the controller or page you get when you enter just the root of the website, like "www.mysite.com/".
I'm aware that I can get the RouteData and use its Values property to get the current page or controller, like string? currentPage = RouteData.Values["page"] as string and then check if currentPage == "/Index". However, what if custom route conventions specify a different name for the home page instead of the default "/Index" page or "/Home" controller?
In short, how can I make a reliable method like the hypothetical IsHome() method, that tells me if I'm in the home page of the website, independently of whether I'm using MVC controllers or Razor pages?

You can inject the HttpContextAccessor and access the "controller" and "action" names using HttpContext.Request.RouteValues
HttpContext.Request.RouteValues
Count = 2
    [0]: {[action, Index]}
    [1]: {[controller, Home]}



Add the service to your Program.cs

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


Create a static class and method that accepts 2 string parameters

public static class HomeHelper
{
   public static bool IsHome(string controller, string action)
   {
      // customize the logic depending on which you want is the home
      return (controller.toLower() == "home" && action.toLower() == "index")
   }
}


Inject httpContextAccessor in your controller and use the static class, in the example below it's home controller

public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

   public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
   {
      _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
   }

   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      var controllerName = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"];
      var actionName = _context.Accessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"];
      
      // this will return true
      var isHome = HomeHelper.IsHome(controllerName, actionName);

      return Content("");
   }
}


The default route your project is indicated in;
Project > Properties > launchSettings.json
then look for launchUrl


You can also indicate another default route or fallback by specifying in your Program.cs; app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");

Although it should work on most scenarios, this assumes the default page name is always "Index" and the default controller name is always "Home". The question focus more on how to take that into account.

@UnknownCoder you can update the logic to whatever your default route is. The default route usually is {controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}

I'm not sure how I should get the default route (the default page name and default controller name). That's where I'm struggling.

@UnknownCoder added instructions where to get the default route, and specifying another default route/fallback via program.cs

Thank you! I wonder how I could get those defaults programmatically, though.

@UnknownCoder you can get it in your controller via the Configuration service;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399076/5640737

Thank you! That's indeed very helpful. I will do that.

This won't work for Razor Pages.

If you want to do this reliably across Razor Pages and MVC Controllers, you can inspect the current EndPoint's metadata and see if the RoutePattern's RawText property is an empty string. If it is, you are on the home page of your application, regardless whether it is served by Razor Pages or an MVC controller. If you want to do this on every request, you should look at implementing middleware or filters, but in essence, you can access the endpoint from the HttpContext of the current request:
var endpoint = HttpContent.GetEndpoint();
var routeEndPoint = endpoint as RouteEndpoint;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routeEndPoint?.RoutePattern.RawText))
{
    // you are on the home page
}

How you implement this (and therefore access the HttpContext for the current request) depends on what exactly you want to achieve, but this should give you a start.

This is a nice approach, which I also considered. However, if I access the home page by specifying the home page name (For example: if I access www.mysite.com/Index), it doesn't work, because the endpoints for both are different, even though it is still the home page.
The endpoint with empty raw text is useful for obtaining the default page name, though, by using its PageActionDescriptor. However, I'm not sure if the RawText property is guaranteed to be empty for the entry page.
Because the IsHome() method is for a library, I have no guarantees about the route configuration.
