# ASP.NET Core HOSTNAME Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a need to define specific configuration properties based on the HOST that is called in my C# ASP.NET Core MVC Application.

I have a webapp (mywebapp) that does functions the same for each user, but pulls data from user defined tables.  I need to be able to detect the subdomain the user is calling to determine what set of tables to pull data from.

Example: if a user calls https://site1.mywebapp.com, the data will be pulled from tables defined only for site1.

Whereas a user calling site2.mywebapp.com would be served data from site2 tables.

This all worked with the global.asax page but is seems with ASP.NET Core, I can no longer detect the users domain at processing.

How can this be done in C# ASP.NET Core?

It would be great to have a base class that all requests would go through where I could detect the subdomain and control the tables a user's data comes from.

Comment: Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526630/how-can-i-get-the-baseurl-of-my-site-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mark.  I was able to find a solution using the information you provided.

1. Create a new BaseController and override OnActionExecuting.  This method gets called before every action.
   [image]
2. Have my HomeController inherit the BaseController.  The HomeController now has access to the SITE the user is looking for.
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely be done. From a RAZOR view you would use `this.Request.Host.Host`, and you can access it in a similar fashion from other components of your application.

[image]

Keep in mind, this is NOT a secure method to determine which data to access.  So if the data isn't shared or public data it should be coupled with validation against some form of authentication token.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this logic in the controller?