# Generate hyperlink in ASP.NET MVC 2 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I've been scouring the web for a way to do this.

I want to generate a hyperlink to an action from my controller and put it in a string. I need to be able to define the label and give it html attributes. I can get `Url.Action(...)` working but that method doesn't let me define the label on the link.

`HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(...)` looks promising but I can't find any concrete examples on how to use it.

The link should look something like this:

```
<a href="/Application/Form?action=view&id=11">View</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a URL in the controller .NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699782/creating-a-url-in-the-controller-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this property to your base controller:

```
    protected HtmlHelper Html
    {
        get
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext( ControllerContext, new WebFormView( Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath ),
                new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), Response.Output )
            {
                RouteData = ControllerContext.RouteData
            };

            return new HtmlHelper( viewContext, new ViewPage() );
        }
    }
```

and then call it from anywhere:

```
var link = Html.ActionLink( "Click Me", "action" );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string str = string.Concat("<a href=\"",ControllernameinVar,"/",ActionNameinVar,"?action=",view,"&id=",variable">View</a>"
```

and then pass this in ViewData and call it in view

```
<%= str%>
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a few ways to do this - here are 2:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")">Link name here</a>

Html.ActionLink(article.Title, 
            "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
            "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
            new { id = "<arguments here" }, // <-- Route arguments.
            null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                  //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                  //     (refer to comments, below).
            )
```

there are other overloads of each available

Comment: this means nothing - do you want to redirect to a specific view (link) for a certain condition in the controller?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a little more information on why you would want to do this would be a little more helpful. If you return a string that contains HTML it will by default be HTML encoded and rendered useless on the client. If you have a custom view where this will be rendered why not build the link there using @Html.ActionLink?

I guess I am trying to figure out the benefit of doing it in the controller rather than the view...

Comment: The link is going to be inserted into a success message that is displayed on the page. The message is only displayed if it is specified in the controller.