# Object reference not set to instance of an object, While using Url.Action() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting error: object reference not set to an instance of an object in this line of code in my Controller class method:

```
var ChangeEmailUrl = Url.Action("ChangeEmailConfirmation", "ManageAccount");
```

My objective is to get a URL path to an action 'ChangeEmailConfirmation' in controller 'ManageAccount'. The string link returned by the Url.Action() method would be sent in an email.

Also, I would like to know if there is any other way to get URL link. Any light on solving this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try with urlhelper or htmlhelper

Url Helper:

Contains methods to build URLs for ASP.NET MVC within an application.

Official doc:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx

HtmlHelper.GenerateLink Method:

Generates an HTML anchor element (a element) that links to an action method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.generatelink(v=vs.118).aspx

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/700357/3397630

Hope it was useful

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get an absolute url 
(http://localhost:8385/MyController/DoThis):

```
  var ChangeEmailUrl = Url.Action("DoThis", "MyController",null,Request.Url.Scheme,null)
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005367/getting-full-url-of-action-in-asp-net-mvc)