# Redirecting to Action Result Using Href Attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Invoke action result from an anchor tag,

I am building html into C# , its not in view and injecting it into view using html helper `@Html.Raw(Model.HTML)` like this.

HTML is

```
html.AppendLine("<td><a href='Home/DeleteFile?ID="+ dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'><i style='color:#e90029' class='fa fa-times fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td>");
```

The Problem is when i click first time on this anchor tag to delete the record it works by invoking address

```
http://WebsiteAlias/Home/DeleteFile?ID=2
```

But after that when i hover to another record to delete them it show URL to

```
http://WebsiteAlias/Home/Home/DeleteFile?ID=2
```

It add Another /Home in url ,

Why it is happening ?

I cant use `@Url.Action("Action","Controller")` cause HTML is coming from c#

Comment: Is this what you want: `<a href='/Home/DeleteFile?ID="+ dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'>`?

Comment: You can use `Url.Action()` in the contoller to generate the correct url

Comment: If you want to use HTML helper, this post already do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699782/creating-a-url-in-the-controller-net-mvc.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes , this is what i want , but it does not work well

Comment: @StephenMuecke , will it work if i add Url.Action() in stringBuilder ?

Comment: Yes - `Url.Action()` outputs a string so you can use `yourStringBuilder.Append(Url.Action(....));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the C# code that builds the HTML has access to the `HttpContext`, you can create an UrlHelper like this:

```
using System.Web;

var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
string url = urlHelper.Action("DeleteFile", "Home", new { ID = dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() });
return url;
```

**Edit**: if you only have access to `HttpContextBase`, you can get the current `HttpContext` like this:

```
HttpContextBase contextBase;
HttpContext httpContext = contextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
```

Comment: Error : HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' . Which reference need to add ?

Comment: `using System.Web`; HttpContext should be available in MVC Controllers, ViewModels, Views, Global.asax, ... Maybe you have to pass it to the class that builds the HTML.

Comment: See also my edit on how to get `HttpContext` from `HttpContextBase`.