# Primeng fullcalendar 4 eventClick does route to '/null'

Tags: angular, primeng, fullcalendar-4

Hey there every time the eventClick() method will be called, it execute it and then it will route to localhost:4200/null. But my calendar is on route localhost:4200/prime-ng. So i tried to redirect the route '/null' to the calendars route. But the component will be initialized new. Then I found this post: [fullcalendar - eventclick changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932252/fullcalendar-eventclick-changing-url)
It's actually the same problem as I have, but he did it with JavaScript. So I though I can do the same with the angular router. But it routes just before the URL will be changed.

```
    eventClick: (el) => this.router.navigate(['/prime-ng']),
```

I would be really thankful if you have some hints and tips for me.

**Compnente**

```
import { EventService } from '../services/event.service';
import { EditorState, Lesson } from '../models/calendar-helper';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendar } from 'primeng';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-primeng-calendar',
  templateUrl: './primeng-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./primeng-calendar.component.sass']
})
export class PrimengCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('calendar', { static: true })
  calendar: FullCalendar;
  events: Lesson[];
  options = {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'addAppointmentButton,dayGridMonth,listView,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    customButtons: {
      addAppointmentButton: {
        text: 'Neuer Event erfassen',
        click: () => this.showEditor = !this.showEditor
      }
    },
    eventClick: (el) => this.router.navigate(['/prime-ng']),
    editable: true,
    locale: 'de',
    allDaySlot: false,
    businessHours: {
      daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5],
      startTime: '08:00',
      endTime: '18:00'
    },
  };
  showEditor = false;
  constructor(private eventService: EventService,
              private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.getEvents().toPromise()
      .then( () => this.events = this.eventService.events);
  }

  onClose(state?: EditorState): void  {
      this.showEditor = !this.showEditor;
      this.events  = [...this.eventService.events];
  }

}
```

**Html**

```
<app-event-editor
  (close)="onClose($event)"
  *ngIf="showEditor"></app-event-editor>

<p-fullCalendar
#calendar
[events]="events"
[options]="options">
</p-fullCalendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue. To prevent it just do this:

```
    eventClick: (el) => el.jsEvent.preventDefault(),
```