# Creating Full URL in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837922/6156888) to a similar question.

My code looks like this:

```
string url = Url.Action("Details", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Area = "MyArea", id = Id }), HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority);
```

However, the resulting url contains double port number like this:

```
http://localhost:54383:54383/MyArea/Home/Details/1
```

The url should be:

```
http://localhost:54383/MyArea/Home/Details/1
```

Comment: You're saying `Url.Action` is creating a URL with the port number duplicated?  Are you doing any kind of string operations on `url` after that line to insert a port number?

Comment: yes port number is duplicated and no there's no other string operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will work fine

```
 string url = Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { Area = "MyArea", id = Id }, HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);
```